# Problems with layout (twitter bootstrap): adding additional column hides the main menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently I'm having difficulties with bootstrap 3.0.x template:
Here is the demo template:

www.kuzma.tk

Before corrections the layout looked this way:

```
left sidebar:           
col-md-2 col-md-offset-1
middle component:
col-md-6
Right sidebar:    col-md-2


Now the layout have been slightly changed:
left sidebar: col-md-2
middle: col-md-7
right sidebar: col-md-2
```

After widening the middle by 1 column the main menu have disappeared! 
If I change the middle to "6" through the FireBug - it appears. I haven't found what's causing the problem...

Need help. Thanks!

Bootstrap v.3.0.2

Comment: Please don't post links to existing web pages, they will be gone or modified in the future. Better distill the relevant code and post it in your question and in a jsfiddle.net. As an additional bonus, you learn how to tackle such problems yourself.

Comment: I could try this, if it will replicate my existent problem

Comment: When I look at your site, you have about 12 CSS stylesheets and about 20 JS includes. You can start, for example, with a minimal [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3vvC/1/) and expand from there. This way it is easier for everybody to see the relevant parts and maybe someone will come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your change your columns sum up to 12. Before the number of columns was 11.
12 columns will fill the grid.

In your style0.css you define margin-right: 2%; on `#right` this will break your grid. The total width of your rows will become > 100%.

**update**
see picture below, this seems to work well (col-md-2, col-md-6, col-md-2, with #left{margin-left:0} and #right{margin-right:0;})

[image]

**update 2**

See your inline stylesheets:

```
.custom div.moduletable ul.nav, html body div#page div#midlle.row div.col-md-6 div#component nav.navbar div.moduletable ul.nav{
    display: block; position: static;
}
```

This rules has a hard coded `div.col-md-6` which set your text menu to display:block. Without the col-md-6 this dropdown menu will have display:none.

Comment: I have added to middle 1 column(col-md-8) and removed all margins from left and right sidebars, but this doesn't fix it :/

Comment: see update. Try to create a fiddle or bootply reflecting your problem and code maybe

Comment: Hi! Yes, with middle column set to 6 is works, but I must make it wider. Here is my first experience with JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b3vvC/17/   Just widen the result box to make fit all three columns. In the white box the menu should be rendered, but it doesn't appear with this layout :( Only with middle column set to 6

Comment: thanks for adding the fiddle. I found the problem only with col-md-8 for the middle columns. Again moving the margin 2% of your #left and #right seems to fix this

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! I've updated the markup: removed the margins and set middle column to col-md-8  http://jsfiddle.net/b3vvC/18/    But the text menu on the white rectangle still doesn't appear. But if I change the middle column to col-md-6, it appears :/

Comment: Great! Thank you! Removing this line few days ago haven't helped and I haven't noticed that there is 'col-md-6'. Many thanks!